# ssh logon with variables

Tags: linux, ssh, command, alias

For work, I often have to log on to several different servers which are generally structured in the following:

> ssh [username]@[clientName]-[product].[domainName]

The username and domain name are always the same, but the client and the product vary. On my previous computer, I was given a script which allowed me to log on to these servers by typing [product] [clientName], but I lost it when I switched PCs and now I don't know how to do that again.

Though I no doubt have been using the wrong search terms or something, I can't seem to find an answer to this question. All my searches lead me to aliases, which work but only for specific commands, not a general one where I can change the variable. I have over 100 clients and many have multiple different products, so an alias for each is impractical.

Could anyone explain how I implement this?

Bonus: It would also be useful for the command to also take me to a specific sub-directory on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In the script, `$0` is the name of the script, and `$1` is the first argument. So the script should do:

```
ssh username@"$1"-"$0".domainName
```

Create the script once with a generic name, then use symbolic links to that for all the product names.

Put the script and all the links in a directory, and add that directory to your `$PATH`.